# Recoding a value in SQL when Date/Time conditions are met with another record from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to answer this question in SQL:

Create Follow_Up:

- 1 if the patient was seen for an outpatient visit within 7 days of being discharged from hospital visit
- 0 if they were not seen for an outpatient visit within 7 days.

A patient who is seen at any point on the 7th day should be flagged (e.g., a patient who presents to the ED on 2/6/2015 at 2AM who had an outpatient follow up visit on 2/13/2015 at 5PM should be flagged as having an outpatient visit within 7 days, even though this is greater than 168 hours apart).

Below is some sample data and the code that I have thus far.  I think this needs to be a sub query as well.  Note, the data sample below would be a different table that I would be looking in than the rest of the code which is why a sub-query would be needed I think.

Note: An outpatient record will not have a `Hosp_admit_dt`. `Hosp_admit_dt` will not have an appointment check in.  Also, note that rows can be in any order.  There is no given offset.  There is a random number of records for each `PAT_KEY`.  The answers thus far seem to need to have a specific offset.  I am not sure that I know how to create one.

Example: Looking at the the following:

Visit `83842766` for patient `8216694` was a hospital admit. The discharge date of `11/10/2014 16:45`. This same patient was readmitted under visit `83883100` at `11/13/2014 14:42`. Since this is under 7 days, there would be a `1` in the `Follow_Up` column for this patient on the visit `83842766` row.

```
SELECT
   [PAT_KEY]
 , [VISIT_KEY]
 , [HOSP_ADMIT_DT]
 , (SELECT --NOT SURE HOW THIS CAN BE DONE) AS 'FOLLOW_UP'
FROM [ESa611337].dbo.[visit$]
WHERE [HOSP_ADMIT_DT] <> 'NA' 
GO
```

Sample Data:

```
VISIT_KEY PAT_KEY DEPT_KEY CONTACT_DT_KEY APPT_CHECKIN_DT  HOSP_ADMIT_DT    HOSP_DISCHRG_DT
85383519  8208755 5153     20150204       2/4/15 9:03 AM   NA               NA
85394064  8208755 4655     20150205       NULL             2/5/15 11:32 AM  2/8/15 7:09 PM
85482578  8208755 4931     20150213       2/13/15 2:41 PM  NA               NA
85687769  8208755 4690     20150325       3/25/15 1:25 PM  NA               NA
85706446  8208755 4804     20150325       3/25/15 1:23 PM  NA               NA
84492982  8211959 4780     20141221       NULL             12/21/14 7:22 PM 12/21/14 9:15 PM
81006886  8215742 4923     20140611       6/11/14 3:56 PM  NA               NA
83502242  8216600 4777     20141016       10/16/14 1:15 PM NA               NA
81239904  8216694 4995     20140531       5/31/14 2:19 PM  NA               NA
81825248  8216694 4655     20140616       NULL             6/16/14 9:19 AM  6/19/14 12:48 PM
81854416  8216694 4995     20141008       10/8/14 8:59 AM  NA               NA
83842766  8216694 8111     20141107       NULL             11/7/14 3:15 AM  11/10/14 4:45 PM
83883100  8216694 4777     20141113       11/13/14 2:42 PM NA               NA
85747526  8216694 4716     20150227       NULL             2/27/15 8:23 AM  2/28/15 3:04 PM
81342608  8217928 4780     20140514       NULL             5/14/14 4:07 AM  5/14/14 5:36 AM
81385263  8217928 4780     20140516       NULL             5/16/14 2:04 PM  5/16/14 5:35 PM
82517665  8218267 4777     20140808       8/8/14 2:36 PM   NA               NA
81239905  8220393 4653     20140511       5/11/14 3:44 PM  NA               NA
86144271  8223186 4780     20150326       NULL             3/26/15 4:19 PM  3/26/15 6:28 PM
83012245  8223203 4780     20140914       NULL             9/14/14 3:38 PM  9/14/14 8:22 PM
85174511  8224572 11611    20150122       1/22/15 12:44 PM NA               NA
83279874  8225752 4780     20141002       NULL             10/2/14 9:59 PM  10/3/14 2:33 AM
84456795  8227359 4777     20141219       12/19/14 9:05 AM NA               NA
85727889  8227359 4998     20150227       NULL             2/27/15 1:15 PM  2/28/15 6:40 PM
86017880  8227509 5061     20150319       3/19/15 2:48 PM  NA               NA
82909082  8230810 11611    20140912       9/12/14 8:23 AM  NA               NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your SQL server version is 2012 and above, then you can try the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function like below

```
Select 
   [PAT_KEY]
 , [VISIT_KEY]
 , [HOSP_ADMIT_DT]
 , CASE 
       WHEN DATEDIFF(d,HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, FollowUpDate) <= 7 THEN 1  -- You may modify this if you want difference by hours
       ELSE 0
       End as FOLLOW_UP
from (SELECT
   *,
   LEAD(SalesQuota, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY PAT_KEY ORDER BY VISIT_KEY) AS FollowUpDate -- This will create a new column by getting the value from next row, 
                                                 --assuming that VISIT_KEY is always have higher value compare to previous visit
FROM [ESa611337].dbo.[visit$]
) query
WHERE [HOSP_ADMIT_DT] <> 'NA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag` to get the values from previous row (based on required ordering) and use a `case` expression with your conditions to set the flag. (Run the inner query to see how previous values would be gotten on to the current row.)

```
select distinct pat_key,
case when appt_checkin_dt is not null 
          and hosp_admit_dt='NA' 
          and prev_dischrg_dt<>'NA' 
          and datediff(day,prev_contact_dt,cast(appt_checkin_dt as date))<=7 
     then 1 
     else 0 
end as follow_up
from (SELECT t.*
            ,lag(contact_dt_key) over(partition by pat_key order by contact_dt_key) as prev_contact_dt
            ,lag(hosp_dischrg_dt) over(partition by pat_key order by contact_dt_key) as prev_dischrg_dt
      FROM [ESa611337].dbo.[visit$] t
     ) t
```

*The solution assumes you are on a SQL Sever version 2012 or later to be able to use the `lag` window function.*

Comment: Does this only work if it is the row before?  The original data is not in sequential order.  Also, if lag is looking at the row before, I can assume that the program will notice if the row before is not the same PAT_KEY?

Comment: i would suggest taking a look at the results of the inner query and also reading the [documentation on lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to understand how the query works.

Comment: Your table alias is wrong, isn't it?  You've got `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT t.* ... FROM [visit$]) t`.

Comment: yeah..missed it in the inner query. added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I'd like to help if I can, but before I go too much further I'd like to make sure my understanding of your need is clear.

Create an environment based on your provided data:

```
-- create table variable --

DECLARE @visits TABLE (
    [VISIT_KEY] INT, [PAT_KEY] INT, [DEPT_KEY] INT, [CONTACT_DT_KEY] INT, [APPT_CHECKIN_DT] DATETIME, [HOSP_ADMIT_DT] DATETIME, [HOSP_DISCHRG_DT] DATETIME
);

-- insert data --

INSERT INTO @visits (
    [VISIT_KEY], [PAT_KEY], [DEPT_KEY], [CONTACT_DT_KEY], [APPT_CHECKIN_DT], [HOSP_ADMIT_DT], [HOSP_DISCHRG_DT]
)
VALUES
  ( 85383519, 8208755, 5153, 20150204, '2/4/15 9:03 AM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 85394064, 8208755, 4655, 20150205, NULL, '2/5/15 11:32 AM', '2/8/15 7:09 PM' )
, ( 85482578, 8208755, 4931, 20150213, '2/13/15 2:41 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 85687769, 8208755, 4690, 20150325, '3/25/15 1:25 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 85706446, 8208755, 4804, 20150325, '3/25/15 1:23 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 84492982, 8211959, 4780, 20141221, NULL, '12/21/14 7:22 PM', '12/21/14 9:15 PM' )
, ( 81006886, 8215742, 4923, 20140611, '6/11/14 3:56 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 83502242, 8216600, 4777, 20141016, '10/16/14 1:15 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 81239904, 8216694, 4995, 20140531, '5/31/14 2:19 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 81825248, 8216694, 4655, 20140616, NULL, '6/16/14 9:19 AM', '6/19/14 12:48 PM' )
, ( 81854416, 8216694, 4995, 20141008, '10/8/14 8:59 AM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 83842766, 8216694, 8111, 20141107, NULL, '11/7/14 3:15 AM', '11/10/14 4:45 PM' )
, ( 83883100, 8216694, 4777, 20141113, '11/13/14 2:42 PM ', NULL, NULL )
, ( 85747526, 8216694, 4716, 20150227, NULL, '2/27/15 8:23 AM', '2/28/15 3:04 PM' )
, ( 81342608, 8217928, 4780, 20140514, NULL, '5/14/14 4:07 AM', '5/14/14 5:36 AM' )
, ( 81385263, 8217928, 4780, 20140516, NULL, '5/16/14 2:04 PM', '5/16/14 5:35 PM' )
, ( 82517665, 8218267, 4777, 20140808, '8/8/14 2:36 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 81239905, 8220393, 4653, 20140511, '5/11/14 3:44 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 86144271, 8223186, 4780, 20150326, NULL, '3/26/15 4:19 PM', '3/26/15 6:28 PM' )
, ( 83012245, 8223203, 4780, 20140914, NULL, '9/14/14 3:38 PM', '9/14/14 8:22 PM' )
, ( 85174511, 8224572, 11611, 20150122, '1/22/15 12:44 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 83279874, 8225752, 4780, 20141002, NULL, '10/2/14 9:59 PM', '10/3/14 2:33 AM' )
, ( 84456795, 8227359, 4777, 20141219, '12/19/14 9:05 AM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 85727889, 8227359, 4998, 20150227, NULL, '2/27/15 1:15 PM', '2/28/15 6:40 PM' )
, ( 86017880, 8227509, 5061, 20150319, '3/19/15 2:48 PM', NULL, NULL )
, ( 82909082, 8230810, 11611, 20140912, '9/12/14 8:23 AM', NULL, NULL );
```

Next, attempt to decipher/query what it is you need:

> Visit 83842766 for patient 8216694 was a hospital admit. The discharge
>   date of 11/10/2014 16:45. This same patient was readmitted under visit
>   83883100 at 11/13/2014 14:42. Since this is under 7 days, there would
>   be a 1 in the Follow_Up column for this patient. We can only see the
>   patient number 1 time in this.

**UPDATED QUERY**

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY v.PAT_KEY ORDER BY v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT ) AS VisitRow
    , v.PAT_KEY
    , v.VISIT_KEY
    , v.CONTACT_DT_KEY
    , v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT
    , v.HOSP_ADMIT_DT
    , v.HOSP_DISCHRG_DT
    , LAG( v.HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, 1, NULL ) OVER ( PARTITION BY v.PAT_KEY ORDER BY v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT ) LastDischarged
    , DATEDIFF (
        dd
        , LAG( v.HOSP_DISCHRG_DT, 1, NULL ) OVER ( PARTITION BY v.PAT_KEY ORDER BY v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT )
        , v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT
    ) AS DaysFromDischarge
FROM @visits v
WHERE
    v.PAT_KEY = 8216694
ORDER BY
    v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT;
```

**UPDATED RESULTSET**

```
+----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
| VisitRow | PAT_KEY | VISIT_KEY | CONTACT_DT_KEY |     APPT_CHECKIN_DT     |      HOSP_ADMIT_DT      |     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT     |     LastDischarged      | DaysFromDischarge |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
|        1 | 8216694 |  81239904 |       20140531 | 2014-05-31 14:19:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL              |
|        2 | 8216694 |  81825248 |       20140616 | NULL                    | 2014-06-16 09:19:00.000 | 2014-06-19 12:48:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL              |
|        3 | 8216694 |  81854416 |       20141008 | 2014-10-08 08:59:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | 2014-06-19 12:48:00.000 | 111               |
|        4 | 8216694 |  83842766 |       20141107 | NULL                    | 2014-11-07 03:15:00.000 | 2014-11-10 16:45:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL              |
|        5 | 8216694 |  83883100 |       20141113 | 2014-11-13 14:42:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | 2014-11-10 16:45:00.000 | 3                 |
|        6 | 8216694 |  85747526 |       20150227 | NULL                    | 2015-02-27 08:23:00.000 | 2015-02-28 15:04:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL              |
+----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

- I kept all the rows for this patient for review purposes and added a VisitRow to help identify, well, a row. Rows 3 and 5 are the ones I believe that matter.
- I have also adjusted to ORDER BY clause to use CONTACT_DT_KEY in lieu of VISIT_KEY.

Question:

- Looking at patient 8208755 has made me question the use of LAG. LAG is only looking at the previous record for a discharge date. Will a ( pertinent ) check-in record **always** have an immediate preceeding discharge record? Is it possible that you may need to look back further than a single row? If so, then LAG will not do what you're looking to do here.

---

The following is an example using CROSS APPLY in the case of patient 8208755 who has multiple check-ins in a row without an immediate preceeding discharge. The CROSS APPLY is simply looking for the last discharge date for the patient.

```
-- patient 8208755 using CROSS APPLY --

    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY v.PAT_KEY ORDER BY v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT ) AS VisitRow
        , v.PAT_KEY
        , v.VISIT_KEY
        , v.CONTACT_DT_KEY
        , v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT
        , v.HOSP_ADMIT_DT
        , v.HOSP_DISCHRG_DT
        , dc.LastDischarged
        , DATEDIFF (
            dd
            , dc.LastDischarged
            , v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT
        ) AS DaysFromDischarge
    FROM @visits v
    CROSS APPLY (

        SELECT MAX( HOSP_DISCHRG_DT ) AS LastDischarged FROM @visits x 
        WHERE 
            x.PAT_KEY = v.PAT_KEY  -- current patient record
            AND x.HOSP_DISCHRG_DT < v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT  -- a discharge date prior to check-in

    ) AS dc
    WHERE v.PAT_KEY = 8208755
    ORDER BY
        v.PAT_KEY, v.CONTACT_DT_KEY, v.APPT_CHECKIN_DT;
```

CROSS APPLY results for patient 8208755 ( all rows ):

```
+----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
    | VisitRow | PAT_KEY | VISIT_KEY | CONTACT_DT_KEY |     APPT_CHECKIN_DT     |      HOSP_ADMIT_DT      |     HOSP_DISCHRG_DT     |     LastDischarged      | DaysFromDischarge |
    +----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
    |        1 | 8208755 |  85383519 |       20150204 | 2015-02-04 09:03:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL                    | NULL              |
    |        2 | 8208755 |  85394064 |       20150205 | NULL                    | 2015-02-05 11:32:00.000 | 2015-02-08 19:09:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL              |
    |        3 | 8208755 |  85482578 |       20150213 | 2015-02-13 14:41:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | 2015-02-08 19:09:00.000 | 5                 |
    |        4 | 8208755 |  85706446 |       20150325 | 2015-03-25 13:23:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | 2015-02-08 19:09:00.000 | 45                |
    |        5 | 8208755 |  85687769 |       20150325 | 2015-03-25 13:25:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    | 2015-02-08 19:09:00.000 | 45                |
    +----------+---------+-----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

This query looks back for the earliest discharge date for a patient and then returns that. In this case: **2015-02-08 19:09:00.000**.

Comment: Yes, but the catch is, you want to compare `APPT_CHECKIN_DT` if it exists to the `HOSP_DISCHRG_DT`.  In the final query, I will only be looking at full hospital stays.  I will be saying, ok this patient checked out of the hospital on some given date, but since this same patient was seen back in the hospital within 7 days (including the 7th day regardless of number of hours that have passed) as an outpatient,  we will put a 1 in this column.  Those that are discharged and come back more than 7 days or never would get a 0.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I have updated my example, @Chris. Is this on track?